# Configurações do eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Na hora de instalar os SDK pelo eclipse como faço para adicionar a biblioteca third party add-ons e Android repository estou usando a última versão do eclipse chamada eclipse mars!

Answer (score 0):

Na aba Help, Install New Software, então basta colocar o caminho do arquivo que você deseja instalar e dar um Finish.